# Charts - Column chart with extra data

Tags: charts, yui

I have some data similar to the following chart:
http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/charts/charts-seriescustomization_clean.html

Only difference is that for each of the fields -  I have some other extra data - say For utlilities - I have a cash reserve for utility - as another field. I would prefer this data point to come above the utilities bar.

I have been trying from morning to get this chart working, but I am unable to do so. Could you please let me know if it is possible - someway?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards
K

Comment: Can you post some code or a link to some code that's not working?  Definitely can set this up, but need to understand the problem better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data that is positive will appear above the origin so any positive data will be above the utilities bar. If you are trying to get your field to appear directly above the utilities bar, you cannot accomplish his with a column chart. You can do this with the stacked column chart. When using the stacked column chart, all items will be stacked. You can convert the above link to a stacked column by changing your chart constructor from ColumnChart to StackedColumnChart:

```
var mychart = new YAHOO.widget.StackedColumnChart
```

and by setting stackingEnabled to true on your vertical axis.

```
currencyAxis.stackingEnabled = true;
```

Tripp